# devtools::document fails when using RStudio shortcut but runs when calling devtools::document()

Tags: r, r-package

I am rebuilding documentation in a custom package in RStudio.  Running R version 3.5.1.  I am able to rebuild the package.  However, when I run Document from the RStudio Build pane (or the shift+com+D shortcut), I get an error:

```
Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA)  : 
Dependency package qdap not available.
```

Now, if I run devtools::document() from the console without any arguments, it runs with no problems.  Note that qdap is listed in the DESCRIPTION files under imports.

Note that the first time I do this, R prompts me to manually install several packages because the previous versions were built under different internals from the new R 3.5.1 version.

I would like to understand what exactly is going on here - why am I getting the error that qdap isn't being found?

Comment: When building packages, you need to specify the dependencies (needed additional packages) in your "DESCRIPTION" file. I'm guessing that qdap is not listed there.

Comment: It is listed there under imports

Comment: I guess we just need to close as not reproducible.

Comment: This is reproducible.  Create a dummy package in Rstudio running r 3.5.1 and put qdap under imports.  Then create a dummy function and document it.  Then run Document from the Build menu.